# How to use gsub and regex to identify and remove consecutive symbols?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a column with values such as this:

```
structure(list(col1 = c(" |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |", "|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |             |", 
"|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ", "stop|", "stop| | ", 
"stop | go")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I want to be able to remove all iterations of `|` when they show up consecutively, or if they show up as `| |` or `| |  |`.

Currently, I'm trying to figure out all the iterations of the pipes, but they seem kind of random. I was wondering if there's a way to make sure my iterations cover the following instances:

1. When there are more than one `|` consecutively
2. When there are more than one `|` consecutively with a number of spaces (e.g., `|  |` or `| |   |`
3. When `|` is at the end of the line (e.g., `\\|$`

I would, however, keep the pipe between `stop | go`.

Here's the code that I'm working with right now, but it removes the pipe in `stop | go`.

```
df$col1 <- gsub('[\\| ]{2,}|[\\|$]', '', df$col1)
```

I want to remove all the `|` symbols except for the one in `stop | go`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this works

```
trimws(trimws(gsub('(\\|\\s+){2,}', "", df$col1),
 whitespace = "\\s+\\|"), whitespace = "\\|")
```

-output

```
[1] ""          ""          ""          "stop"      "stop"      "stop | go"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
gsub('\\|\\s*\\||\\|\\s*$', '', df$col1)
#> [1] "       "                   "                         "
#> [3] "              "            "stop"                     
#> [5] "stop "                     "stop | go"
```

And a simple `trimws` if you don't want the spaces this leaves behind, as in akrun's answer:

```r
trimws(gsub('\\|\\s*\\||\\|\\s*$', '', df$col1))
#> [1] ""          ""          ""          "stop"      "stop"     
#> [6] "stop | go"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another regex strategy is to remove `|`'s not followed by space and word:

```
trimws(gsub("\\|(?!\\s\\w)", "", df$col1, perl = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
[1] ""          ""          ""          "stop"      "stop"      "stop | go"
```